# Can apache superset dual axis chart change the range of Y axis?

Tags: python, apache-superset

Now, apache superset, I think that we can not change the range of dual axis line chart.

https://superset.incubator.apache.org/index.html

I think the lower limit of the Y axis is from the minimum value to the maximum value.

For example, if it is a graph of percentage, can you change the range from 0 to 100 with apache superset?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the configuration options of the dual axis time series line chart are not (yet?) as advanced as they are with the standard one. The one you mentioned is just one of them.

I guess the best option you have is to either file an issue on github or implement it yourselve an create a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

After many trials, I have found that if you turn the aggregate into a "metric" of Superset, you will get a better range distribution. Especially if you are comparing percentage with percentage you will have both 100% for Y axises.

[image]